# How to get or calculate threshold value for Ostu Thresholding?

Tags: opencv, visual-c++

I have been faced problem to find the optimal threshold value. So plz help to find that how to select best threshold value for otsu threshold.

Comment: OpenCV computes the value automatically. Why do you want to compute it? And why do you need it?

Comment: [Here](http://imagej.net/Auto_Threshold) (from [ImageJ](https://imagej.net/Welcome) library, [licensing](https://imagej.net/Licensing)) you can find some other techniques for automatic thresholding in case you want to find some other references. The source code is available and can be translated easily to OpenCV C++.

Answer (score 2):

OpenCV computes the threshold for OTSU automatically, so you rarely (if ever) need to know what the threshold value is.

You can however retrieve it as the return value of the `threshold` function:

```
double otsu_threshold = cv::threshold(src, dst, 0 /*ignored value*/, 255, cv::THRESH_OTSU);
```

Comment: Just to be explicit, the `threshold` argument passed to the function is ignored when using `cv::THRESH_OTSU`.

Comment: Actually i am using emboss and deboss object for edge detection.  So,  every this type of object has more than one boundary. Outer boundary is easily detected by this function cv:: THRESH_OSTU.  But,  same process i applied for inner boundary.  I can't get accurate result. So,  plz give me suggestion for any modified Ostu algorithm,  which result is the better than  this function.

Comment: @KajalPrajapati Can you be more elaborate? What is **emboss** and **deboss**? And  where is the image you intend to work with? More details -> More expectations!!

Comment: @Kajal I answered your question. If you have a another question or further details that consistently change your original question (like in this case), please ask a new question.

Comment: I am work on edge detection for emboss or deboss object.  Just like dove shop..  Its outer shape is oval,  but inner dove pattern shape is deboss on dove shop.  So,  outer boundary is easily detected by Ostu thresholding. But, same process is apply for inner deboss boundary detection.. I can't get accurate result. And my challenge work is that no other edge detect.. Only detect outer boundary and emboss or deboss boundary of object.

Comment: @KajalPrajapati now you know how to get the threshold value of OTSU, and this answers your original question. So please accept this answer and ask a new question, with images, actual and expected results, and the code you have so far ([mcve])

Comment: I have no more time to ask new question..  So plz suggest any modified ostu algorithm step.

Comment: @Kajal this is not how this site works. Also, without seeing some images and results there's not much I can do anyway. Sorry

Comment: Plz plz suggest me modified ostu algorithm step.. How to calculate and get result. Its very urgent for me..